# MySQL Connector/MXJ: authentication issue

Tags: mysql-connector, access-denied, mysql, connector-j

I would like to get started with MySQL Connector/MXJ. I am not sure how the authentication works. Where do I specify the actual user/password pair before connecting to mysqld?

I tried the following URL connection to no avail:

```
jdbc:mysql:mxj://localhost:3336/bignibouTest?server.basedir=/home/julien/tmp&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&server.initialize-user=true&server.initialize-user-name=root&server.initialize-user-password=root
```

I systematically get "`java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`".

Maybe it if someone could let me know how not to use a password, it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One satisfactory workaround I found it to specify `server.initialize-user=false` and use:

- user:"root"
- password:""

in other words, MySQL's default password for root seems to be an empty string.

As far as unit tests are concerned this is OK.